# NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for #<Ingredient:0x0000000005e6cf30>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have come across this error a few times this week, but this time I have no idea what is wrong. I have an ActiveRecord Model called `Ingredients`

```
class CreateIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :ingredients do |t|

      t.string :title , null: false
      t.integer :availability
      t.decimal :price, precision:15, scale: 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the application record I have for it:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true

  has_many :ingredient_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :ingredient_categories
end
```

Now I try to create a new Ingredient on the irb but I get an error saying:
 `NoMethodError: undefined method 'title' for #Ingredient:0x0000000005e6cf30>`

This is the exact output on the console:

```
irb(main):003:0> Ingredient.create!(title: 'Cheese Spread')
#=> ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'title' for Ingredient.
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please try Ingredients.new and check whether you have 'title' column displayed?

Comment: You should try this from `rails console` not from IRB.

Comment: goto your rails app by `cd /path/to/railsapp` --> then do `rails console` and try

Comment: Please show your `schema.rb`

Comment: @VigneshwaranSivalingam I get     "NameError: uninitialized constant Ingredients". Do u know why?

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy this is what I did!

Comment: according to your question - it is pointing from irb - `irb(main):003:0> Ingredient.create!(title: 'Cheese Spread') ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: `. please change it - and also update your `schema.rb `file here.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy I was on the app folder and then gave the command *rails c*. Isnt this how you can get to the console?
also what update should I do in the schema? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ffblord pls share the `schema.rb`. most probably you forgot to run the migration. if the `ingredients` table in the schema file does not contain `title` column, just run `rails db:migrate` and check the schema again to see if the column appears now. If yes, you can retry creating the record again.

Comment: Could you share your schema.rb file? seems as though you didn't run your migration

Answer (score 1):

Try `rails db:migrate` if you have not added this migration and then use `rails console`.

What you probably did was rails db:migrate when you first created the table, but after you added the columns you did not and so when you went to create an Ingredient, it knew what the table was, thus why it could not go further than title.